# I am having trouble fixing my code which tries to generate a random sudoku board using python 3x

Tags: python

This code is able to generate some rows but suddenly it goes into a infinite loop i suppose. please somebody fix this code.

```
import numpy as np
import random


soduku = np.zeros(shape=(9,9))

for i in range(0,9,1):
    for j in range(0,9,1):
        while True:
            x = random.randint(1,9)
            if x not in soduku[i,:] and x not in soduku[:,j]:
                soduku[i,j] = x
                if j == 8: print(soduku[i,:])
                break
```

Comment: @MaheshReddy you need to revisit you solution. First of all, think about the algorithm. After this check what is your code doing. If it works - great, if not, try to print what is happening and when you have more concrete question post again on StackOverflow. Most likely the code cause troubles because of `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty in that you have no provision for backtracking.  Look at your inner loop:

```
    # i and j are "given" at this point.
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1,9)     # grab a random number
        # Is it legal to put the number in this square?  If not, keep looping
        if x not in soduku[i,:] and x not in soduku[:,j]:
            soduku[i,j] = x
            if j == 8: print(soduku[i,:])
            break
```

Now let's look at a simple situation, a partial fill, at the end of the second row:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 _
```

We want to fill the last spot in the second row.  However, no matter what number you pick in the range 1-9, the number already exists in either that row, or in the last column.

Your program has no way to back up and try again: it simply keeps choosing a random number and trying to put it there.

You need to research Sudoku filling algorithms.  These are readily available on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line.